# Use Bluetooth Keyboard with Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, bluetooth, keyboard

I read that you could use Bluetooth Keyboards since a certain Windows Phone 8.1 version. What update do I need for this and how do I connect the keyboard to my phone? And does this work in every app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluetooth keyboards are only supported with Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2 which will only be released officially [on a select set of phones](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-confirms-windows-phone-81-update-2-select-smartphones) (ie. not all WP8 phones).

Currently, the Lumia 640 and 640 XL come with Update 2.

For most other phones, [it is possible to install Update 2 unofficially as part of the Windows 10 for phone preview programme](http://www.neowin.net/news/heres-how-to-get-windows-phone-81-update-2-on-some-lumias). Phones install Update 2 as part of the process before Windows 10 is installed.